# Project $f(x) = \sin^2(x)$ onto the plane spanned by $\sin(2x)$ and $\cos(2x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

I approached the problem by projecting $f(x)$ onto each of the other functions (since they are an orthonormal basis) using the formula $$\langle f(x),\sin2x\rangle \sin2x + \langle f(x),\cos2x\rangle \cos2x.$$

Before I go through the computations, I wanted to make sure this is the correct approach. Thanks!

Comment: This is the correct approach if indeed $\sin(2x), \cos(2x)$ form an orthonormal basis but they actually might form only an orthogonal basis depending on the particular space and inner product you are working with. What is the space you are working on and what is the inner product?

Comment: If you don't specify neither the linear space nor the inner product this can't possibly be done...unless you feel like guessing the missing data, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with the *Fourier series* (which is likely, because the two basis you give are orthogonal Fourier bases), your formula is how the projection should work.

Observation: If you're not required to show the process, just notice that
$$
\sin^2x = 1-\cos^2x = 1-\frac{1+\cos2x}{2} = 1-\frac{1+\cos2x}{2} = \frac{1}{2} -
 \frac{1}{2}\cos 2x.
$$
The extra constant $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}$ is for the basis of $1$, which is orthogonal to both $\sin 2x$ and $\cos 2x$.